# Repeat array and stops at specific position w/ numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have to write a cyclic functie `cyclisch(N)` that constructs a Numpy-row with length N with content`[1.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 ...]`.

This is de code I'm having now.

```
import numpy as np
import math

def cyclisch(N):
    r = np.linspace(float(1.0), float(3.0), 3)
    return np.repeat(r, N//3) + r[0:N%3-1]
```

I tried multiple times to make the list 'r' float, but I get the error:

```
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Further, the repeating code is also wrong. With the repeat coding you get:

```
[ 1.  1.  2.  2.  3.  3.]
```

Instead of `[1.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 ...]`. Does anyone know how to have this kind of repeating code?

This is the control mode:

```
p = cyclisch(10)
q = cyclisch(7)
assert np.all(p == np.array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.])),'Fout resultaat van cyclisch(10)'
assert np.all(q == np.array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.])),'Fout resultaat van cyclisch(7)'
print('Correct !')
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [np.resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html).

```
>>> np.resize([1., 2., 3.], 5)
array([ 1., 2., 3., 1., 2.])
```

This works since:

> If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of a.

Note that the `np.ndarray.resize` *method* has different behavior, padding with zeros (and also mutating the array instead of making a new one), so you need to use the function, not the method.

Comment: Wow, this is more concise and should be considered as better solution.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
>> N = 5
>> x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
>> np.asarray(x * (N // 3) + x[:N % 3])
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.])
```